# zip exclude folders on centos7

Tags: centos, zip

i tested the following commands below, but without success...
How can i exclude specific subdirectories (and all files inside them) on CentOS 7?

```
zip -r file.zip /var/www/html/ -x "/var/www/html/exclude1/" -x "/var/www/html/exclude2/" -x "/var/www/html/exclude3/"

zip -r file.zip /var/www/html/ -x /var/www/html/exclude1/**\* /var/www/html/exclude2/**\* /var/www/html/exclude3/**\*

zip -r file.zip /var/www/html/ -x /var/www/html/exclude1/ /var/www/html/exclude2/ /var/www/html/exclude2/
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is the following:

```
zip -r file.zip /var/www/html/ -x "/var/www/html/exclude1*" "/var/www/html/exclude2*" "/var/www/html/exclude3*"
```

Example:

I have created a few dirs and files under `/tmp/tozip`, each dir contains a `test.txt` file.

```
$ find /tmp/tozip/ -type d
/tmp/tozip/
/tmp/tozip/exclude
/tmp/tozip/fol1
/tmp/tozip/fol1/exclude
/tmp/tozip/fol2
/tmp/tozip/fol2/exclude
/tmp/tozip/fol3
/tmp/tozip/fol3/fol2
/tmp/tozip/fol3/fol2/fol1
/tmp/tozip/fol3/fol2/fol1/exclude

$ find /tmp/tozip/ -wholename '*exclude/*'
/tmp/tozip/exclude/test.txt
/tmp/tozip/fol1/exclude/test.txt
/tmp/tozip/fol2/exclude/test.txt
/tmp/tozip/fol3/fol2/fol1/exclude/test.txt

$ zip myzip.zip -r /tmp/tozip -x "/tmp/tozip/fol1/exclude*" "/tmp/tozip/fol2/exclude*" "/tmp/tozip/fol3/fol2/fol1/exclude*" "/tmp/tozip/exclude*"
  adding: tmp/tozip/ (stored 0%)
  adding: tmp/tozip/fol1/ (stored 0%)
  adding: tmp/tozip/fol1/test.txt (stored 0%)
  adding: tmp/tozip/fol2/ (stored 0%)
  adding: tmp/tozip/fol2/test.txt (stored 0%)
  adding: tmp/tozip/fol3/ (stored 0%)
  adding: tmp/tozip/fol3/fol2/ (stored 0%)
  adding: tmp/tozip/fol3/fol2/fol1/ (stored 0%)
  adding: tmp/tozip/fol3/fol2/fol1/test.txt (stored 0%)
  adding: tmp/tozip/fol3/fol2/test.txt (stored 0%)
  adding: tmp/tozip/fol3/test.txt (stored 0%)
  adding: tmp/tozip/test.txt (stored 0%)
```

My zip:

```
$ zip -help
Copyright (c) 1990-2008 Info-ZIP - Type 'zip "-L"' for software license.
Zip 3.0 (July 5th 2008). Usage:
```

Test for the op to perform:

```
mkdir -p /tmp/tozip/exclude /tmp/tozip/fol1/exclude /tmp/tozip/fol2/exclude  /tmp/tozip/fol3/fol2/fol1/exclude

find /tmp/tozip/ -type d -exec touch "{}/test.txt" \;

zip myzip.zip -r /tmp/tozip -x "/tmp/tozip/fol1/exclude*" "/tmp/tozip/fol2/exclude*" "/tmp/tozip/fol3/fol2/fol1/exclude*" "/tmp/tozip/exclude*"
```

Comment: You could use something like `.... -x "/var/www/html/exclude[1-3]*/*"` to catch all.

Comment: ti tryed this, but actually it doesn't work, it still adds files inside the ignored folders

Comment: strange, on my server this doesn't work as expected

Comment: Ok, which zip are you using ? Also, what are the directory names, if I may ask ... they might contain special characters or something ....

Comment: zip 3.0 from 2008

Comment: I know this is not good practice, but see no other option. Please perform the three commands in my answer, you should get the same output as me, without exclude dirs and files therein.